# How to properly install Breeze for production

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I'm using Laravel Breeze, when I want to host it, it gives me a big problem that one user wants to login while another user is open. When I was installing Breeze, I used this command:

```
composer require Laravel/breeze --dev
```

I tried

> composer require Laravel/breeze --dev

my expectation was to normal install Laravel/breeze for authentication

Comment: what does it mean "that one user wants to login while another user is open" exactly?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the breeze:install Artisan command to install Breeze's views and routes to your application. Run the following command in your terminal:

`php artisan breeze:install`

Comment: I have done all the commands below
php artisan breeze:install
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev